# Phaser BitmapData Sprite Immovable on Drag

Tags: phaser-framework

I am a noob with Phaser games in general but I am trying to make a  scrabble like game.

I made my tiles as BitmapData and added to sprite.  I want to be able to drag and drop them on my scrabble board but not be able to place one tile in a spot where another tile is.

For debugging purposes Ive been just trying to get the individual tiles to respect each other's physics when you drag and drop.  The behavior I want is, when dragging, to bump into another tile with that tile "holding its ground" and the dragging tile unable to cross on top of the other tile.  Currently the dragged tile just goes on top of other tiles.  I've looked at a lot of examples and feel that my issue may be either because my sprite is made with bitmapData or something around the drag event...

```
function makeTile (tileIndex, tile) {

    var bmd = game.add.bitmapData(canvasZoom, canvasZoom);

    // draw to the canvas context 
    bmd.ctx.beginPath();
    bmd.ctx.rect(0, 0, canvasZoom, canvasZoom);
    bmd.ctx.fillStyle = '#efefef';
    bmd.ctx.fill();
    bmd.ctx.fillStyle = '#234234';
    bmd.ctx.font="20px Georgia";
    bmd.ctx.fillText(tile.tileName, 7,23);


    // use the bitmap data as the texture for the sprite
    var tileSprite = game.make.sprite((tileIndex * canvasZoom) + canvasZoom, canvasZoom, bmd);
    game.physics.arcade.enable([tileSprite]);
    tileHandGroup.add(tileSprite);

    tileSprite.inputEnabled = true;

    var bounds = new Phaser.Rectangle(canvasZoom, canvasZoom, spriteWidth * canvasZoom, (spriteHeight * canvasZoom) + (canvasZoom * 2));
    tileSprite.input.boundsRect = bounds;

    tileSprite.name = 'tileSpriteName' + tileIndex;

    tileSprite.input.enableDrag(true);
    tileSprite.input.enableSnap(canvasZoom, canvasZoom, true, false);

    tileSprite.immovable = true;
    tileSprite.body.moves = false;

    tileSprite.events.onDragStart.add(onDragStart, this);
    tileSprite.events.onDragStop.add(onDragStop, this);
}

  function firstTileHand() {

    tileHandGroup = game.add.physicsGroup(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    game.physics.enable(tileHandGroup, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    tileHandGroup.enableBody = true;
    tileHandGroup.name = 'tileHandGroup';


    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
    {
        makeTile(i, tiles[i]);
    }
}
```